# No "Run Python Console" in PyCharm menu

Tags: python, console, pycharm

I am new to PyCharm and I am stuck on something really stupid: I cannot get Pycharm to display a Python interpreter console window.

The help tells me to click "Tools -> Run Python Console" in the main menu, which is simple and logical enough, except there is no Run Python Console command in my Tools submenu. There is a "Tools -> Python Console..." command (yes with the dots, plus an icon), but it does nothing. Ditto for the "Python Console" box (with the same icon) in the right end of the bottom bar.

I have searched a lot for a solution, but nobody seems to have discussed this or a similar problem.

My installation is:
PyCharm Community Edition 2016.1.2,
Build #PC-145.844, built on April 8, 2016,
JRE: 1.8.0_60-b27 x86,
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM by Oracle Corporation

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Click the icon in the lower left corner of pycharm, then you will get a button for the console.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The icon does open a menu which includes "Python Console", but that doesn't work either. On the other hand, the "Terminal" command in the same menu does open a window with a Windows (or old-time DOS) command prompt.

Comment: Have you installed python on your pc?

Comment: Apparently, yes, because I can execute a python program under PyCharm. The output displays in a window which looks like a Python console, but goes dead upon program completion and won't let me type anything.

Comment: Sorry - what is idle?

Comment: If you have a moment, please take a look at the configuration settings for the console, in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Python Console.

Comment: My settings are: the "Environment variables:" box is empty; the "Python interpreter" is set to default; the Interpreter options and Working directory boxes are both empty. The Add Content roots... checkbox is checked, the Add source roots... is not, and the Starting script is import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend([WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS])

Comment: idle is the interactive python interpreter. It is used for the python console

Comment: It is installed as a program and you can run it

Comment: Found and ran idle. It complains about being unable to create a working directory, and a separate Python 2.7.11 Console window appears, popping up a "Subprocess Startup Error" message box that says "IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection. Either IDLE can't start a subprocess or personal firewall software is blocking the connection". When I acknowledge the message, the console window disappears.

Comment: Is your python installation added to the PATH variable? It is an option in the installation you can select, or you can add it manually later.

Comment: My PATH variable conains a number of Python-related entries, the most promising of which is "C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\SciTE-3.5.
1-4;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\console"

Comment: Then you will need to add the location of your python installation to the PATH. Otherwise programs can't find the python interpreter.

Comment: It seems to already be there. My full PATH includes PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Program Files (x86)
\nodejs\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python
27\Scripts;C:\Python27\gnuplot\binary;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\SciTE-3.5.
1-4;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\console;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\swig
;C:\Program Files\Anaconda2;C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\Program Files\
Anaconda2\Library\bin;C:\Anaconda2;C:\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\Anaconda2\Library\bin
;C:\Users\lleszek\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: BTW StackOverflow thinks this discussion is getting long, and suggests I move it to chat - is that OK with you?

Comment: Well it's not OK with... StackOverflow itself. It suggested switching to chat, but now it won't let me - I don't have enough reputation (only 1). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Which files do you use and edit? what are the names of the files?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. The file I edit is a program I copied from an example somewhere on the web, but it works (or fails to, depending on my modifications) more or less normally. Its filename, for whatever it's worth, is K3_AABB1.py - K3 is my personal prefix, AABB stand for the CGAL structure i'm learning to use, 1 is for my first attempt to use it. Why do you ask?

Comment: Because a filename like 'string.py' or 'time.py' could cause issues with the interpreter because they are python defaults. But that isn't the case then.

Comment: The part about the path is ok, i read it too fast and thought you meant it didn't had the python path.